# Haproxy ProxyPass and ReverseProxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, haproxy, proxypass

I have an Apache vhost with the following directives ;

```
ProxyPass "/String1" "http://10.0.1.50:8081/String1/String2/String3
ProxyPassReverse "/String1" "http://10.0.1.50:8081/String1/String2/String3"

ProxyPass "/String2" "http://10.0.1.100:8080/String1/String2/String3
ProxyPassReverse "/String2" "http://10.0.1.100:8080/String1/String2/String3
```

How do I do this in Haproxy? I tried with the following ;

```
Frontend Apache
bind *:8993
mode http
option httplog
option httpclose
option http-server-close
option forwardfor
acl url_string1 path_beg /String1
acl url_string2 path_beg /String2
use_backend string1 if url_string1
use_backend string2 if url_string2

backend string1
mode http
server string1 10.0.1.50:8081/String1/String2/String3

backend string2
mode http
server string2 10.0.1.100:8080/String1/String2/String3
```

but it's not doing the trick. I hope someone can help me out as it's really pissing me off.

Comment: What version of HAProxy (`haproxy -v`)?  1.6.x and later make it quite a bit easier to do things like this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the version is 1.8.17

Comment: Funny how something so simple in apache gets so god damn complicated on haproxy.